How to modify an existing Variable created with StaticVariable in Soong?
How to modify an existing Variable created with StaticVariable (see below) in Soong?
Is it possible at all?

From package_ctx.go:
// StaticVariable returns a Variable whose value does not depend on any
// configuration information.  It may only be called during a Go package's
// initialization - either from the init() function or as part of a package-
// scoped variable's initialization.
//
// This function is usually used to initialize a package-scoped Go variable that
// represents a Ninja variable that will be output.  The name argument should
// exactly match the Go variable name, and the value string may reference other
// Ninja variables that are visible within the calling Go package.
func (p *packageContext) StaticVariable(name, value string) Variable {

